# How to reference function from another library in my SalesforceInteractions SDK sitemap

Tags: datacloud

I am building a sitemap for that will stream data into Data Cloud. The website uses Sitecore Engage and this CMS create a browerId value for each user that I would like to capture and pass through to Data Cloud. On the console I am able to retrieve this value with engage.getBrowserId().

To develop the sitemap I used the SalesforceInteractions browser extension, and while using this editor was able to successfully capture the browserId value with const browserId = engage.getBrowserId(), and pass it through events (according to the debug log and dataset panel).

However, now that I have loaded the sitemap into Data Cloud I am getting the  error:
**"Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: engage is not defined"**

How can I leverage external JS libraries within my sitemap such as this engage.getBrowserId() method?